# Formula translation for Mars calculator

Tags: python, calculator, trigonometry

I need to translate this formula into Python:

```
δs = arcsin {0.42565 sin Ls)} + 0.25° sin Ls
```

having in mind that Ls value is 122.985º (in degrees)

The code I´m using is:

```
Ls = 122.985
Ds = math.asin(math.radians(0.42565 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls)))) + 0.25 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls))
```

The result for Ds is around 0.2159º... when it should be around 21,128º.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the first `math.radians` should not be there.

Comment: Removing the first Math.Radians results in 0.5748. What's the name of this formula or what are you trying to calculate?

Comment: It´s D-1 Determine solar declination (planetographic). as seen on this page https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/mars24/help/algorithm.html

Comment: And this is the referenced paper. Formula is number 5. https://pubs.giss.nasa.gov/docs/1997/1997_Allison_al04000r.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the formula has a degree mark on the second term. It's saying "take the arcsine of 0.42565 times sine(Ls). That is an angle, which can be expressed in degrees. To it, add 0.25 degrees times sine(Ls)".

```
angle1 = math.degrees(math.asin(0.42565 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls))))
correction = 0.25 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls)) # this is a value in degrees
Ds = angle1 + correction
```

Or combine into one formula, I broke it out for clarity above

```
Ds = math.degrees(math.asin(0.42565 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls)))) + 0.25 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls))
```

Working your example:

```
>>> Ls = 122.985
>>> angle1 = math.degrees(math.asin(0.42565 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls))))
>>> angle1
20.918572663722518
>>> correction = 0.25 * math.sin(math.radians(Ls))
>>> correction
0.20970328134223665
>>> angle1 + correction
21.128275945064754
```

Don't put too much weight on my labelling the second term a correction, I got that from discussion in http://www.oregonl5.org/mist/docs/Mars24J/help/notes.html, in particular:

> For an accurate account of the solar illumination relative to the
>   plane of a locally flat surface, the solar declination can be
>   corrected for the small difference appropriate to the so-called
>   planetographic measure of latitude on an oblate sphere, as it is in
>   the Mars24 sunclock.

but I could be misinterpreting what that's saying. The main thing I'm sure of is that the values test out and the units carry through sensibly.

Comment: That´s exactly what I was looking for, thanks Peter!